# mongo_mapper - undefined method `call' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby, mongomapper

Hi Trying to install mongo_mapper and this is the error I get.

```
gem install mongo_mapper

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `call' for nil:NilClass
```

anyone have a idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to  be with the 1.6.0 version of the mongo gem that was released a couple of days ago. Installing version 1.5.2 of the mongo gem worked fine.
Try installing the mongo gem before you install mongo_mapper:

```
gem install mongo -v 1.5.2
```